# How to find the right cartopy projection?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I need to plot some data in Germany with cartopy. The data part of my plot works fine (so I deleted it for now). Unfortunately, the shape of the country is deformed due to the projection.

I am currently using the PlateCarree projection, but changing it to Orthographic or others created the same plot.

How to improve the shape?

[image: Link to image of output vs. wanted output]

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io import shapereader

# get country borders
resolution = '10m'
category = 'cultural'
name = 'admin_0_countries'
shpfilename = shapereader.natural_earth(resolution, category, name)
df = geopandas.read_file(shpfilename)
poly = df.loc[df['ADMIN'] == 'Germany']['geometry'].values[0]

# plot
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([5.8, 15.1, 47.25, 55.1],
              crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_geometries(poly,
                  crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  facecolor='gainsboro',
                  edgecolor='slategray',
                  lw=0.1,
                  alpha=.8)

# save plot
save_path = 'germany.png'
plt.savefig(save_path, dpi=250, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you post the code you tried for the orthographic projection instead? That should do what you’re hoping so we might be able to debug your call.

Comment: Dear Michael, thanks for your answer. Yes, the Orthographic Projection did the trick, my mistake was not transforming the Geopandas Dataframe. I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is transforming the Geopandas Dataframe using the same projection as explained [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/cartopy_convert.html?highlight=add_geometries#CartoPy-to-GeoPandas)

**New output:**
[germany.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYZQG.png)

**New code:**

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
    import geopandas
    from cartopy.io import shapereader

    # get country borders
    resolution = "10m"
    category = "cultural"
    name = "admin_0_countries"
    shpfilename = shapereader.natural_earth(resolution, category, name)
    df = geopandas.read_file(shpfilename)
    df_de = df.loc[df["ADMIN"] == "Germany"]


    extent = [6., 14.8, 47.1, 55.1]

    # plot
    crs = ccrs.Orthographic(
        central_longitude=(0.5 * (extent[0] + extent[1])),
        central_latitude=(0.5 * (extent[2] + extent[3])),
    )

    crs_proj4 = crs.proj4_init

    df_de.crs = "EPSG:4326"
    df_ae = df_de.to_crs(crs_proj4)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": crs})
    ax.set_extent(extent)
    ax.add_geometries(
        df_ae["geometry"],
        crs=crs,
        facecolor="gainsboro",
        edgecolor="slategray",
        lw=0.1,
        alpha=0.8,
    )

    # save plot
    save_path = "germany.png"
    plt.savefig(save_path, dpi=250, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.0)
    plt.close()
```